# How to execute an “insert into” query to a remote database with channel.connect();

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jsch, remote-connection

This is the java code I have tried to insert into my remote database table.

```
session.connect();
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

String query = "INSERT INTO table_name
(id,serialno,userid,checktime,checktype,eventType) 
VALUES(502,1011,0078,'2017-04-17 17:27:51',6,23)";

((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("mysql -uuser -ppwd -h localhost -e'" + 
query + "' database_name");
    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
    channel.connect();
```

I used the same code to execute "select *" query, instead for "Insert query" it executed perfectly and I got the output. But in this case it doesn't. Please help me find a solution.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say, "in this case it doesn't". What were you expecting?  Did you get an error response?  Did you run a query to see whether your insert worked?

Comment: @BPS :this is my question - How to execute an “insert into” query to a remote database with channel.connect(); I didn't get any error while execute the query for insert. But the "insert" not reflected in the remote database.
I am expecting a perfect query to insert into remote database

Comment: @BPS :Why you give down-vote for no reason? If you read my question top to bottom with Head Line, you could be easily understand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and other community guidelines.  People here want you to get help even if they can't answer your question.  Helping you to improve your question is one way that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need to escape double quotes With  `\"` , because double quotes are used as delimiters in Java.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO table_name
(id,serialno,userid,checktime,checktype,eventType) 
VALUES(502,1011,0078,'2017-04-17 17:27:51',6,23)"                

((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("mysql -uroot -proot -h localhost -e\"" + query + "\" yourdbname");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the same command on command-line?

```
mysql -uuser -ppwd -h localhost -e'INSERT INTO table_name (id,serialno,userid,checktime,checktype,eventType) VALUES(502,1011,0078,'2017-04-17 17:27:51',6,23)' database_name
```

It would not work either. The quotes in the `INSERT` command conflict with the quotes on the command-line, that wrap the SQL command.

One way is to use double-quotes on the command-line:

```
mysql -uuser -ppwd -h localhost -e"INSERT INTO table_name (id,serialno,userid,checktime,checktype,eventType) VALUES(502,1011,0078,'2017-04-17 17:27:51',6,23)" database_name
```

Then in Java, you have to escape those double quotes as `\"`, because Java uses double-quotes to delimit the string.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried(with backslash) the same code in command-line and also in java.It didn't work.

Comment: You are right. One cannot escape single quotes the way I suggested. I've fixed my answer.